# Bootstrap collapse jQuery addClass/removeClass to only the one that was clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Part of the problem is that I'm not sure how to phrase what I want...

Here's my jQuery

```
$(".view-bio").click(function(){
if($("h2 a").hasClass("collapsed")) {
    $("h2 a").removeClass("collapsed");
} else {
    $("h2 a").addClass("collapsed");
}
});
```

I have an unordered list that is generated in WordPress. Everything works, except when you click, it is adding/removing the class from all the list items - not just the one clicked.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a sample of the HTML, so that we can correctly answer your question?

`$("h2 a")` will select all `a` elements that are contained in an `h2`.

Comment: @KenrickChien here's the site: http://clients.kaplusa.com/aces/about/executive-team/

Answer (score 0):

Try this jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kakashi/FsLax/

The problem is that you are selecting all links, not the one that is clicked.

See my sample code in the jsFiddle; I use `$(this)` to refer to the element which triggered the click event, and toggle the `collapsed` class only on that particular element.

Edit: here is the code I used:

```
$('h2 a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

Hope this helps.